# Copy selected files iteratively over ssh

Tags: linux, ssh

Suppose I have files numbered 1.txt through 5000.txt on a server and I want to copy files numbered 1800.txt through 5000.txt to my local system. How do I do that? Normally, for copying all, I would use `scp -r` but that won't work for this.

Comment: You can use wildcards.

Comment: I am not familiar with that. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
scp user@host:/path/to/remote/'{1800..5000}.txt' /path/to/local
```

we quote the brace-expansion to prevent interpret that by your local servers' shell; instead it will expand by remote servers' shell.

Answer (score 0):

With a shell that supports "brace expansion" (e.g. `bash` or `ksh`), you could try

```
scp user@$remotehost:{1800..5000}.txt /local/path
```

Comment: I think your answer is saying the same as mine but yours will fail as your local server shell will expend the brace-expansion or am I missing something here different?

Comment: No it doesn't fail. I was thinking the same with your quoted brace expression. But it seems both are working; admittedly yours is faster as it hands the brace expression to the remote server... hopefully the shell over there knows how to expand it.

Comment: ah, right, in your case it expands all to like `scp  user:host:1800.txt user@host:1801.txt ... user@host:5000.txt /local/path` that's why it's slow